# simple pigeonhole question

Tags: combinatorics

Question from an exam.

In a university there are $40$ students. Every student prepares a list of $20$ other students he is willing to share his room with (Rooms are only able to hold 2 students.)

Show that there are at least $2$ students willing to live with each other.

I honestly can't think of what is the pigeon and what is the pigeonhole. How do you approach such a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to consider a graph where each student is a vertex, and an edge from $a$ to $b$ means "a is willing to live with b", you're looking for two vertices $x,y$ with an edge going in each direction (one from $x$ to $y$ and one from $y$ to $x$).

There are $\binom{40}{2} < 40*20$ such pairs of vertices. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I think I understand you. there are $\binom{40}{2}$ ways to make pairs from the group of the students, and there are 40*20 requests...so there is a couple that has more than 1 request

Comment: Right, and I take it you've already understood what a couple with more than 1 request entails. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let (i,j) denote that student i wishes to live with student j. There are 1,560 distinct ordered pairs of the form (i,j) with i not equal to j and 1 < i,j < 40. Since the students choose 800 ordered paris there must exist i,j such that (i,j) and (j,i) belong to this list of 800. If we discard (j,i) whenever we include (i,j) we end up with 1600 distinct ordered pairs, which is a contradiction.